# Bing web service client (Java)

Tags: java, web-services, bing

I want use bing web services and I have my Bing appid.
I have installed eclipse helios (EE), tomcat6, axis2, maven2, and so on.
In my eclipse I go to File->New->Other->Web service client. Then I enter [WSDL file path](http://api.search.live.net/search.wsdl). Verification is ok. Eclipse build some classes in my project but I can't use Bing web services. [Bing documentation](http://www.bing.com:80/developers/s/API%20Basics.pdf) (.Net) uses `LiveSearchService` class but I don't have this class (really it's an interface).

Answer (score 0):

You didn't say explicitly where the problem was...

In general consuming a ws is easy and there are many tutorials on this:

```
HelloWorldService service = new HelloWorldService();
HelloWorld port = service.{a getter method for port..by convention i believe it isgetHelloWorldPort()};
port.myMethod();
```

Was this helpful?
If not, please be more explicit.

Comment: The problem is that LiveSearchService class doesn't exist. But don't worry, I no longer need.